# Justifying the output of toLatex function of utils R package

Tags: formatting, r, sweave, knitr, rnw

Using  `utils::toLatex(sessionInfo())` in `.Rnw` we can get `R Session Info` to put in `LaTeX`. I would highly appreciate if someone guide me to fully justify the output of `utils::toLatex(sessionInfo())`. Thanks in advance for your help.

---

### MWE

---

```
utils::toLatex(sessionInfo())
```

---

### Output

---

```
\begin{itemize}\raggedright
  \item R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10), \verb|x86_64-w64-mingw32|
  \item Locale: \verb|LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252|, \verb|LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252|, \verb|LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252|, \verb|LC_NUMERIC=C|, \verb|LC_TIME=English_United States.1252|
  \item Base packages: base, datasets, graphics, grDevices, grid,
    methods, splines, stats, tools, utils
  \item Other packages: brew~1.0-6, car~2.0-21, foreign~0.8-61,
    Formula~1.1-2, gdata~2.13.3, ggplot2~1.0.0, hexView~0.3-2,
    highr~0.3, Hmisc~3.14-4, knitr~1.6.15, lattice~0.20-29,
    MASS~7.3-34, memisc~0.96-9, mgcv~1.8-2, nlme~3.1-117, plyr~1.8.1,
    psych~1.4.8.11, pwr~1.1.1, reshape2~1.4, rgl~0.93.1098,
    scales~0.2.4, stargazer~5.1, survival~2.37-7, xtable~1.7-3
  \item Loaded via a namespace (and not attached): cluster~1.15.2,
    colorspace~1.2-4, digest~0.6.4, evaluate~0.5.5, formatR~1.0,
    gtable~0.1.2, gtools~3.4.1, labeling~0.3, latticeExtra~0.6-26,
    Matrix~1.1-4, munsell~0.4.2, nnet~7.3-8, proto~0.3-10,
    RColorBrewer~1.0-5, Rcpp~0.11.2, stringr~0.6.2
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: remove `\raggedright` to get justified text

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for your comment. I know removing `\raggedright` will do the trick. But this is the output of `R` in `.Rnw` document so this will overwrite it for every compilation. Is there any way to undo the effect of `\raggedright` without removing it? Thanks

Comment: `\let\raggedright\relax`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for your comment. Would you mind to change your comment to answer. Thanks

Comment: mvkorpel's solution is more complete  (also using renewcommand instead of let, which is more official  latex:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily redefine `\raggedright` to do nothing. The output may not look pretty:

[image: Output from example code]

`.Rnw` file (process with knitr, then LaTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\let\oldraggedright\raggedright
\renewcommand\raggedright{}
<<echo=FALSE,results="asis">>=
utils::toLatex(sessionInfo())
@
\let\raggedright\oldraggedright
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution and Good workaround.